# need help Mahout in Action chapter 2 examples

Tags: mahout

i need your help
i want setup recommender system with mahout
i install java & eclipse & maven on centos 6 then itegerated eclipse with maven
mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.1.0 (893ca28a1da9d5f51ac03827af98bb730128f9f2; 2013-06-28 06:45:32+0430)
Maven home: /usr/local/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_21, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_21/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-71.el6.i686", arch: "i386", family: "unix"
then i install mahout according to your  instruction and total step done successfully
but when check command:
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="mia.recommender.ch02.IREvaluatorIntro" -Dexec.args="src"

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) on project mia: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: intro.csv -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

i am beginner please help me to resolve error
i need your help
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would start by checking that the file intro.csv is available and usable.